# Big issue with set currentTime video on IE10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video

This problem occurs when I set current time of video to 0 by function in IE10:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.currentTime = 0;
```

After that, I get current time of video:

```
alert(vid.currentTime);
```

However, current time which return is not "0" but is always a constant "0.0667334". I tried other version of IE but the result is still the same.

Other browsers (i.e Chrome, Firefox) operate normally and return 0 after get current time.

For more detail, you can see and try example below on IE. It very very simple for understanding our problem.

```
<body> 

<button onclick="getCurTime()" type="button">Get current time position</button>
<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 0 seconds</button><br> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="12345678901.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function getCurTime() { 
    alert(vid.currentTime);
} 

function setCurTime() {             
    vid.pause();        
    vid.currentTime = 0;

} 

</script>
```

Comment: I ran a test on IE11 and it seems to work fine. I get "0" when I click on the "Get current time position" button. Which other versions of IE have you tried?

Comment: IE11 seems to run normally. I used IE10 and IE9. Could you try IE10 and IE 9?